# Vscode is changing the code I wrote after saving the file, why?

Tags: reactjs

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOJDw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lON9e.png)

I'm writing code for a task in a react course and after the file is saved it simply changes what I wrote and a bunch of errors appear and o I don't know why. The first pic is what I wrote, and the second one what happened after I saved the file. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

This never happened to any other code I wrote before.

Comment: Have you installed any VS Code extensions that could possibly try to format your code when you save a file?

Comment: If you look in package.json, do you have anything that mentions 'lint' or 'prettier'?

Answer (score 0):

Your VS Code settings are probably set to run a linter (ESLint maybe?) when you save your file. You can check your settings in the VS Code workspace settings: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings. If you hover over the red squiggly lines it will hint at the errors in your code.

It's been awhile since I've worked in React, but I think you might need to wrap your return in a string literal (backticks: ``). You also might want to use Typescript or JSX with React.

You can also post a sample on Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/ if you want more help.